# Clang: error: invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

Is this gcc being overly nice and doing what the dev thinks it will do or is clang being overly fussy about something. Am I missing some subtle rule in the standard where clang is actually correct in complaining about this

Or should I use the second bit of code which is basically the how offsetof works

```
[adrian@localhost ~]$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -ansi a.cc
[adrian@localhost ~]$ a.out
50
[adrian@localhost ~]$ cat a.cc
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
   char name[50];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::cout << sizeof(Foo::name) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}


[adrian@localhost ~]$ clang++ a.cc
a.cc:10:29: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'name'
   std::cout << sizeof(Foo::name) << std::endl;
                       ~~~~~^~~~
1 error generated.
[adrian@localhost ~]$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -ansi b.cc
[adrian@localhost ~]$ a.out
50
[adrian@localhost ~]$ cat b.cc
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
   char name[50];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::cout << sizeof(static_cast<Foo*>(0)->name) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}


[adrian@localhost ~]$ clang++ b.cc
[adrian@localhost ~]$ a.out
50
```

Comment: Well I found adding -std=c++11 stops it complaining. So now I wonder which part for c++98 I am violating with this code. Gcc is fine with it in either version but that doesn't mean I did not break a rule

Comment: Don't extend your question by adding comments. Either answer your own question, accept it it ask a new question. Or edit your question, including title, and removal of not necessary parts.

Answer (score 1):

> I found adding `-std=c++11` stops it complaining. GCC is fine
>   with it in either version.

Modern GCC versions allow this even in `-std=c++98` mode. However, older versions, like GCC 3.3.6 of mine, *do* complain and refuse to compile.

> So now I wonder which part of C++98 I am violating with this code.

Wikipedia explicitly states that such a feature was added in C++11, and refers to [N2253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2253.html), which says that the syntax was not considered invalid by the C++98 standard initially, but then intentionally clarified to disallow this (I have no idea how non-static member fields are any different from other variables with regard to their data type). Some time later they decided to make this syntax valid, but not until C++11.

The very same document mentions an ugly workaround, which can also be seen throughout the web:

```
sizeof(((Class*) 0)->Field)
```

It looks like simply using `0`, `NULL` or `nullptr` may trigger compiler warnings for possible dereference of a null pointer (despite the fact that `sizeof` never evaluates its argument), so an arbitrary non-zero value might be used instead, although it will look like a counter-intuitive “magic constant”. Therefore, in my C++ graceful degradation layer I use:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    #define CXX_MODERN 2011
#else
    #define CXX_LEGACY 1998
#endif


#ifdef CXX_MODERN
    #define CXX_FEATURE_SIZEOF_NONSTATIC
    #define CxxSizeOf(TYPE, FIELD) (sizeof TYPE::FIELD)
#else
    // Use of `nullptr` may trigger warnings.
    #define CxxSizeOf(TYPE, FIELD) (sizeof (reinterpret_cast<const TYPE*>(1234)->FIELD))
#endif
```

Usage examples:

```
// On block level:

class SomeHeader {
public:

    uint16_t Flags;

    static CxxConstExpr size_t FixedSize =
#ifdef CXX_FEATURE_SIZEOF_NONSTATIC
        (sizeof Flags)
#else
        sizeof(uint16_t)
#endif
    ;


}; // end class SomeHeader



// Inside a function:

void Foo(void) {

    size_t nSize = CxxSizeOf(SomeHeader, Flags);

} // end function Foo(void)
```

By the way, note the syntax difference for `sizeof(Type)` and `sizeof Expression`, as they are formally not the same, even if `sizeof(Expression)` works — as long as `sizeof (Expression)` is valid. So, the most correct and portable form would be `sizeof(decltype(Expression))`, but unfortunately it was made available only in C++11; some compliers have provided `typeof(Expression)` for a long time, but this never was a standard extension.