# Is it illegal get `sizeof` non-static member of struct nested within class template?

Tags: c++11, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, clang++

In clang/llvm 3.6.2, the following code results in a compilation error when compiling with `std=c++11`:

```
template <typename T=void>
class bar
{
public:
    struct foo
    {
        int array[10];
    };

    int baz()
    {
        return sizeof(foo::array);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    bar<> b;
    return b.baz();
}
```

Command line invocation:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 nonstatic.cpp -o nonstatic
nonstatic.cpp:12:28: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'array'
        return sizeof(foo::array);
                      ~~~~~^~~~~
nonstatic.cpp:20:14: note: in instantiation of member function
'bar<void>::baz' requested here
    return b.baz();
```

If I change `bar` to be no longer a template, as in

```
class bar
{
public:
    struct foo
    {
        int array[10];
    };

    int baz()
    {
        return sizeof(foo::array);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    bar b;
    return b.baz();
}
```

then the code compiles cleanly. Of note, GCC 5.2.1 accepts both versions under `std=c++11`. Also of note, moving `array` into the enclosing class template body (but leaving it as a template) also results in clang accepting this.

Which behavior is correct vis-à-vis the standard? Is this a bug in GCC, clang, or both?

(I asked the same [question](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-users/2016-March/000897.html) on cfe-users, but so far have received no response).

Comment: Looks like a clang++ bug. Waiting gurus to confirm that.

Comment: Yes, certainly a bug.

Comment: The workaround `sizeof(((foo*) 0)->array)` mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359661/clang-error-invalid-use-of-non-static-data-member applies here too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is certainly a clang bug; the operand of your `sizeof` expression is an *id-expression* denoting a non-static data member, so **[expr.prim.general]**/13 holds. Here's a reduced example:

```
template<class T> struct M { int f() { return sizeof(T::x); } };
struct S { int x; };
int main() { return M<S>{}.f(); }
```

The bug exhibits when a dependent type member is accessed in an unevaluated context within a template instance method. Clang's implementation of the [n2253 rule enabling the use of non-static data members in unevaluated context](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2253.html) (and later improvements) appears rather fragile and to interact badly with templates; a similar (though distinct) bug is http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20151019/141535.html.

I can't find any indication that this has already been reported to [Clang Bugzilla](https://llvm.org/bugs/); you may want to open a new bug.

Depending on your situation, workarounds may include moving the static type and value calculations outside the instance method; notably even making `baz` a `static` member function is enough to persuade clang to accept your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll go ahead and file a bug with the Clang bugzilla. My use case has the length of the array as a (simple) function of one of the template parameters, so it's very easy for me to just use that instead of calling `sizeof`.

Comment: The bug has been fixed: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/e4193c5ff01b3e3ef48a2c501e07eaa88683f885